# How can i recive Selected Index Page in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm a beginner at iPhone development. I set **95 pages** with (320, 480) pixels in  scrollView content size.

I want to get the **selected index** when I scroll in the `UIScrollView`.

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Selected page %d",scrollView.contentOffset.x) ; 

    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    NSUInteger i;

    for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
    {



        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page (%d).png", i];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;

        rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;

        rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;

        imageView.frame = rect;

        imageView.tag = i;

        NSLog(@"Selected page %d",scrollView.contentOffset.x) ;

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];

        [imageView release];
    }

    [self layoutScrollImages];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do after  getting that selected index number.because you can
check the condition like if sender.tag==5 if you want to use at other place as you have assigned tag to each page  or you can implement scrollview with paging.check this 
example 
https://github.com/ykyuen/ScrollViewWithPaging